# Is there a widely used STOMP adapter for Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, activemq-classic, stomp

I checked out stomper and it didn't look complete. (I'm very new to Python) Is anybody out there using stomper in a production environment?

If not, I guess I'll have to roll out my own Twisted Stomp adapter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

There is a python library called [stomper](https://github.com/oisinmulvihill/stomper) which I've used in the past with twisted (it comes with twisted example code). Disclaimer, I've worked on the code for stomper so I like it :)

These days I've moved away from stomp/ActiveMQ towards AMQP + [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), using the [txAMQP](https://launchpad.net/txamqp) and [py-amqplib](http://barryp.org/software/py-amqplib/) libraries. I've found rabbit more reliable and the AMQP protocol quite good. See [this article](http://blogs.digitar.com/jjww/2009/01/rabbits-and-warrens/) for a very good overview. A big bonus is good java and .net library support too.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted Stomp adapter would be way too cool. Would you consider sharing it and keep us up to date with the development?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

We just open-sourced one that's built on top of stomper:  https://github.com/mozes/stompest

Comment: looks god, going to use it I think. Just one thing, `easy_install stompest` didn't work, had do `easy_install http://github.com/mozes/stompest/tarball/master`

Comment: Ah, thanks.  This was my module submitted to PyPi so I didn't know to upload the source.  easy_install should work now.